# configuring spring security for HTTP POST method

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security 3.0.

I want to disable authentication for a url that handles POST method.  This doesnt seem to work -

```
<http  use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/api/feedback/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <anonymous/>
</http>
```

method="POST" doesnt seem to be working and I get an authorization error POSTing to that url.

What should I do?

Comment: one of the reasons i love stackoverflow is that i get answers quickly!  no replies???? someone please help!

Comment: Does it work differently if you change IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY to permitAll()?

Answer (score 0):

Considereing the `permitAll` is working, I can tell that you're using expressions, so you must change `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` to `isAnonymous()` or `permitAll`

edit: other way, should be to change to `hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')`

your shot ;)